# MetricsQL, Victoria Metrics - Compute average of value every hour

Tags: promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I'm using Victoria Metrics and I have a MetricsQL query to return an array of timeseries (timestamp and value) matching a condition.

I want to compute the averages of these values over a particular period in a single query execution for performance reasons.

For instance,
I'm querying the timeseries for the past 6 hours.
I need averages of the values within 1 hour buckets. So,
The first average value should cover the time range from current time to 1 hour ago.
The second average should cover the time range from 1 hour ago to 2 hours ago, and so on

I figured I need to use `avg_over_time` for this. However, that can only return a single value where as I would need 6 different value pairs in the result.

Does anyone happen to know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong about `avg_over_time`: it returns results for every expected time point (based on parameters `start`, `end` and `step` of `api/v1/query_range` endpoint of API).

So if you query something like `avg_over_time(my_metric [1h])` with `start` and `end` corresponding to some six hour period, and step `1h`, you'll get exactly what you want.

[Here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/api/v1/query_range?query=avg_over_time(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode=%22user%22%7D%5B1h%5D)&start=1706282489.867&end=1706304089.867&step=1h) is demo of query to Prometheus, but Victoria should produce same results.

Answer (score 1):

The per-hour average of some metric can be obtained via [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#avg_over_time) function passed to the following APIs in VictoriaMetrics and Prometheus:

1. [/api/v1/query_range](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#range-query). For example, the request to `/api/v1/query_range?query=avg_over_time(some_metric[1h])&start=-5h&step=1h` should return per-hour average values per each time series matching `some_metric` [filter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#filtering) for the last 6 hours.
2. [/api/v1/query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#instant-query). For example, the request to `/api/v1/query?query=avg_over_time(some_metric[1h])[6h:1h]` should return the same results as the previous query to `/api/v1/query_range`. It uses [subquery functionality](https://valyala.medium.com/prometheus-subqueries-in-victoriametrics-9b1492b720b3) together with little-known ability to return multiple results per series from `/api/v1/query` as described [here](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639).

P.S. Do not forget [properly escaping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) query args passed to the http API handlers mentioned above.